# Rewrite php extension prior to html on nginx

Tags: php, nginx, server

I am trying to rewrite an extensionless server request to the corresponding php file. So far I managed to do so, but I'd like to rewrite php prior to html, so when I have to files with the same file name, it first tries to find the php-version of the file and only if it doesn't exist as php, try to find it as html. I don't know if this makes any sense or not, I was just wondering if it would be possible to get the php-version of a file prior to the html one. My code looks like this, but if I change the location of `@extensionless-php` whithin the `try_files` line, it either results in an `404` or a `500` error. My code looks like this:

```
root path/to/root;
index index.php index.html;

try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;

location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;

        # cgi-params
    }

location @extensionless-php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }
```

If anyone knows a way to accomplish that or has some further input to this, let me know.

Comment: Not sure if the question makes sense. You're talking about extensionless requests and rewriting to PHP. I don't see where HTML comes in.

Comment: HTML comes in when there are two files with the same name, one ending with _.html_ and one with _.php_. I want it to rewrite php first and if that doesn't work (i.e. the file doesn't exist in a "php-version"), fall back to rewriting it as html.

Comment: I'd suggest you update your question with that as it does clarify the question by a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible approach is to remove the `$uri.html` clause from your `try_files` statement and try both extensions in the named location block. For example:

```
root path/to/root;
index index.php index.html;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location ~ \.php$ { ... }

location @rewrite {
    if (-e $request_filename.php) {
        rewrite ^ $uri.php last;
    }
    if (-e $request_filename.html) {
        rewrite ^ $uri.html last;
    }
}
```

Note that the `if` directive comes with the following [safety warnings](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

Comment: This is more or less what I was looking for. Thank you.